# Convert quoted strings in a CSV to an NSMutableArray without the quotes

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsmutablearray

I have a question about the objective C. I have the following NSString *name shown below:

```
 "First Name","Second Name","Last Name";
```

Actually, name is the header of the CSV and receive from the URL. And I use the follow statement to break the statement to array.

```
NSMutableArray *csvTitleArray;
csvTitleArray = [[name componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
```

The result of the array is

```
[0] = "First Name"     // the " is part of the string, it means the first char of [0] is ", not F
[1] = "Second Name"
[2] = "Last Name"
```

However, I want to cancel the " in the begin and end of the string (the " is part of the string. Can anyone help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [parsing csv data](http://www.macresearch.org/cocoa-scientists-part-xxvi-parsing-csv-data), the **General CSV** section (code example) handles your case.

See [writing parser using nsscanner - csv](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/11/writing-parser-using-nsscanner-csv.html) for usefull more generic pointers about parsing data.

Answer (score 2):

Have you thought of using [stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-SW6) and then splitting the string out into an array?